# Change vertical space between numbered formula in LyX

Tags: spacing, equations, lyx

I have inserted serveral (20) Numbered formulas directly behind eachother in LyX 2.0.3. If I export these formulas to the final version in PDF, there is a large vertical space between the formulas.

Is there a way to solve this by changing a setting in the document preamble?

```
\begin{equation}
x_{ij}^{m}R_{ij}^{t_{ij}}\rightarrow Y_{ij}^{t_{ij}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Don't use two or more consecutive `equation` environments; you can use a single `gather` environment (if no alignment is required).

Comment: In LyX words, *Insert --> Math --> AMS gather environment*. Ctrl + enter to start a new line within the `gather`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yet that would imply to redo all the +50 formulas and lose the current refences I've added to each of them ?

Comment: @GijsHompes nop; using `gather` each individual line is numbered and can receive a label for cross-references.

Comment: Meaning I could paste all my existing formulas in the gather environment and continue (remember I am using Lyx)

Comment: I wasn't able to copy-paste from an equation to a gather and bring the label along, but it could be that there is some trick to make it work. Another thing you could check to limit the problem is to remove paragraph breaks between equations (if any). Move the cursor to just after an equation and hit delete. If you have the (complete) source view open, you'll see that an empty line between `\end{equation}` and `\begin{equation}` disappears.

Comment: I have succesfully placed all formulas into a gather environmnent. The problem now is that the formulas don't break to a next page. Meaning that 10 formulas are shown on page a, but the next chapter is on page b as where I'd expect the rest of the formulas...

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved by the help of you guys and an other page on Tex !
The first step is indeed to put all the equations in a gather environment. If needed this can be easily done using Scite (text editor) to avoid losing label data in Lyx. 
Once this step is completed the user might be confronted with a secondary problem being that the gather field is able to "overflow" a page.

The fix for this problem is easy: Just add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the document preamble.

Et Voila ! Thanks again for your help guys!